# Rappasoft datatables v1

Tags: laravel, datatable, datatables, laravel-8

does anyone know how could I setup date filter. Right now I am using standard way of doing it by

```
public function query(): Builder
    {
        return Model::query()->when($this->getFilter('someDate'), fn ($query, $type) => $query->where('someDate', $type))
```

But it constantly returns me error like this

```
TypeError
array_sum(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, bool given
```

Comment: where is `array_sum`?

Comment: that is in core php file and I had to make custom workaround for this to work ^^

Comment: try to trace to your code, and send array not bool.

Comment: nothing worked because there was used function in package which used PHP core function which had some issues (tried update package and PHP and nothing helped). So I extended package model/method and made changes I needed and now all works like a charm :)